# Вычисление в строке типа nowdoc

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно произвести вычисления в строке типа nowdoc

```
$v[VAL] = 5;
$v[VAL2] = 2;
echo "{$v[VAL]} -{$v[VAL2]}<br>";
```

Если я сейчас запущу код то, выведется значение 5 - 2, а мне нужно чтобы произошло арифметическое действие

Answer (score 1):

```
$v['VAL'] = 5;
$v['VAL2'] = 2;
echo $v['VAL'] - $v['VAL2'];
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3faaafd76c0194abeda32fb1873f1430f285886)

Comment: ваш вариант - это самый очевидный ответ. Но! Задача заключается в воде именно в строке с {}

Comment: @васькабот вашем случае арифметическое действие произвести не получится

Comment: всем спасибо разобрался

Answer (score 1):

В PHP есть [4 вида строк](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc): в двойных кавычках, в одинарных кавычках, heredoc и nowdoc.

Какие либо [обработки переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) можно делать в строках в двойных кавычках и в `heredoc`.

Вы не сможете внутри строки использовать какие либо составные операции. Максимум, на что можно рассчитывать - вызов метода.

Т.е. можно использовать такой финт ушами (только смысл?):

```
<?php
class A{
    public function stub($a){
        return $a;
    }
}

$a = new A();

$x=2;
$y=3;
echo "{$a->stub($x+$y)}";
```

Comment: Откуда вы придумали название howdoc?
просто опечатку допустил

Comment: @васькабот  nowdoc в принципе ничего подставить нельзя